# Dragtable plugin not working for dynamic table added

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using dragtable plugin for reorder columns in my web application. It works well for static tables which gets loads with the page. But it is not getting applied to the table as table is generating dynamically on page. Could anyone help me initiating it after dynamic table loads on the page.

```
Dragable plugin link: http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kslagdive/LfKvN/
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply call the dragtable method makeDraggable:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var table = $('<table id=table class="draggable" cellpadding=2 border="1" style="background:#f3f3f3" ><tr><th>test</th><th>test</th><th>test</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table>').appendTo('body');
    // the object has to be a HTML DOM Object, not a jQuery object, so I use
    // table[0] to receive it
    dragtable.makeDraggable(table[0]);
});
```

Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/zEhV5/).

Answer (score 0):

You could just reinitialize the plugin after it has been dynamically added to the page.
I'm guessing in the `$(document).ready` of your page you are doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourTable').draggable();
});
```

Just call `.draggable` on the table again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twitter-bootstrapTable you can add this to your `onLoadSuccess` function

```
onLoadSuccess: function() {
     $table.on('all.bs.table', function (event) {
         $('#table-javascript').dragtable('destroy').dragtable({});
     });
}
```